# hyperledger fabric error: Canceled desc = context canceled

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, grpc

i have ubuntu 16 and hyperledger fabric 1.4.

I am have problems with the order when starting a command on the peer.

```
Error reading from 10.2.11.77:52640: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
```

Also, have problems with the order when run chaincode through my app.

```
Error reading from 10.2.11.77:52640: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
Error sending to 10.2.11.77:52640: rpc error: code = Internal desc = transport: transport: the stream is done or WriteHeader was already called
```

link to logs http://papajon12345.asuscomm.com/nextcloud/index.php/s/BTj4JAHmR29XSC3

Comment: Have you got it resolved?